# JavaScript alert on click event if no checkboxes are checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

Every thing works normally except when I check all the rows and try to delete them with a button.

I put an alert in the delete button which tests if any rows are checked, so when I click the button and no boxes are checked, it shows the alert.

Also when all the boxes are checked how do I change it or where do I put it?
I am new to JavaScript and php.

Or can I change it to a delete confirmation alert!

Here is my code .

```
<script>

function checkUncheckAll(){
var chks = document.getElementsByName("ck");
if(document.getElementById("ck_All").checked)
    {
        $("#delete_link").on("click" , deleteSelectedRows);
        for( i = 0;i < chks.length;i++)
            document.getElementsByName("ck")[i].checked = true;
    }
else {
            for( i = 0;i < chks.length;i++)
            document.getElementsByName("ck")[i].checked = false;
            document.getElementById("delete_link").onclick = function(){deleteSelectedRows();};
    }
}
function selectUnselect(checked){
if(!checked)
    document.getElementById("ck_All").checked = false;
else {
        document.getElementById("delete_link").onclick = function(){deleteSelectedRows();};
        var chks = $("input[name='ck']");
        var all_checked = true;
        for(i=0;i<chks.length;i++)
            if(chks[i].checked)
                continue;
            else {all_checked = false; break;}
        if(all_checked)
            document.getElementById("ck_All").checked = true;
     }
}
function deleteSelectedRows(){
    var cks = $("input[name='ck']");
    var checked = [];
    for(i = 0;i<cks.length;i++)
        if(cks[i].checked)
            checked.push(cks[i].parentNode.parentNode.id);

    var jsonob = JSON.stringify(checked);
    $.post("deletecom.php" , {rows_to_be_deleted:jsonob} , function(data){
        for(i=0;i<checked.length;i++)
            $("#" + checked[i]).fadeOut('slow' , function(){$(this).remove();});
        });
    }
    </script>


<a id="delete_link" onclick="alert('Aucune case n est cochée')">Supprimer</a>
<br><br>

<?php
    $con = new mysqli('localhost' , 'root' , 'etud' , 'responses');

    echo "<div id='divtable'>";
    echo '<table class="table" >';
    echo '<tr id="throws"> 
        <th><input id="ck_All" type="checkbox" onchange="checkUncheckAll()" />Select</th>
        <th>Nom</th>
         <th>Email</th>
         <th>Sujet</th>
         <th>Messages</th>
          <th>Date Creation</th>';

 // if (isset($_POST['date'])& isset($_POST['btncherche'])) {
    error_reporting(E_PARSE);
    $datechoosen=$_POST['date'];
    $result = $con->query("select * from tb_cform where datecreation='".$datechoosen."'");   
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
        echo '<tr id="' . $row['id'] . '">
            <td><input name="ck" onchange="selectUnselect(this.checked)" type = "checkbox" /></td>
            <td>' . $row["u_name"] .'</td>
            <td> '. $row["u_email"] . '</td>' .  
            '<td>' . $row["subj"] . '</td>' .
            '<td>' . $row["message"] . '</td>' .
            '<td>' . $row["datecreation"] . '</td>' .
            '</tr>';

    echo '</table>';
    echo "</div>";

/*  }else{
        echo "veuillez choisir la date S.V.P !";

    }*/
 ?>
```

When I click the delete button the alert keeps showing no matter what the condition is, help me please!
[image]

Comment: Please add the HTML that your PHP outputs.

Comment: i am displaying data from my sql database into a table with check boxes on each row, to let the user select wich row he would like to delete or if he wants all rows but look in the <a> of the button i put an alert

Comment: Please show the output HTML - we do not need to see the PHP, just the HTML that the JavaScript is working with.

Comment: i just did post an image below, sorry for my english and i ont know exactly how stackover flow work

Comment: Ok, please update your question with the HTML that your PHP script outputs for the table in the image. You can get this from Chrome inspector by copying the element code.

Comment: You can also remove the PHP tag from the question as the PHP code is not part of your question problem, this is strictly a JavaScript problem.

Comment: Please also delete the image from the answer below, and add to the question above by clicking the edit link.

Comment: i post it to see the calls of function in the th tags

Comment: I don't know if this can help you but it can be a starting point in order to help you. I created [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fhsuoj6u/1/) adding a confirmation dialog. When you click OK the dialog will call your delete function. I hope this could help you to rephrase your question.

Comment: @salah Yes - but those remain in the HTML that the PHP outputs, please copy the HTML code for the table from your browser and paste this in the question - this will help to provide an answer. Having to read the the PHP makes it harder to understand the context of the problem.

Comment: @SebCooper  you can just edit the question yourself rather than making heaps of comments demanding OP change it to meet your standards.

Comment: no  the delete process work fine in the data base the problem is with the alerts dialgo, by the way @gaetanoM it doesnt show the dialog .

Comment: Updated JSFiddle with jQuery:  https://jsfiddle.net/fL91x2am/8/

Comment: thank you @SebCooper but why did you delete the onclick from the button?

Comment: is there any seggestions, or ani types of dialogs to put it when the rows are all checked or no one in the button?

Comment: I am working on an alternative for you to look at...

Comment: Please approve my edits for clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing I must point out is that it is best to keep your click event handlers out of your HTML and bundled with the rest of your JavaScript, see [Why is using onClick() in HTML a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871640/why-is-using-onclick-in-html-a-bad-practice).

Please see my working example on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fL91x2am/23/

Working code:

```
<script>
    function deleteSelectedRows(){
    var cks = $("input[name='ck']");
    console.log(cks.length);
    var checked = [];
    // Add ids of checked messages to checked array
    for(i = 0;i<cks.length;i++){
        if(cks[i].checked){
            checked.push(cks[i].parentNode.parentNode.id);
        }
    }

        // AJAX delete POST
    var jsonob = JSON.stringify(checked);
    $.post("deletecom.php" , {rows_to_be_deleted:jsonob} , function(data){
        for(i=0;i<checked.length;i++){
            // hide deleted messages row if delete POST successful
            $("#" + checked[i]).fadeOut('slow' , function(){
                $(this).remove();
            });
        }
    });
}

function checkUncheckAll(){
  // var chks = all checkboxes
  var chks = document.getElementsByName("ck");

  // if select all checkbox is checked
  if(document.getElementById("ck_All").checked) {

    for( i = 0;i < chks.length;i++ ){
      document.getElementsByName("ck")[i].checked = true;
    }

  } else {

        for(i = 0;i < chks.length;i++){
      document.getElementsByName("ck")[i].checked = false;
        }
    }
};

function selectUnselect(checked){
    if(!checked){
    document.getElementById("ck_All").checked = false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("delete_link").onclick = function(){
            deleteSelectedRows();
        };
        var chks = $("input[name='ck']");
        var all_checked = true;
        for(i=0;i<chks.length;i++){
            if(chks[i].checked){
                continue;
            } else {
                all_checked = false; 
              break;
            }
        }
        if(all_checked){
            document.getElementById("ck_All").checked = true;
        }
    }
}
// Here we use jQuery's document ready event listener to add the click event listener to #delete_link.  
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#delete_link').on('click', function(){
    // (jQuery syntax) - check if number of checked inputs with name attribute of 'ck' is zero
    if($('input[name="ck"]:checked').length === 0){
      alert('Please select an item!');
    } else {
    // or confirm if the user really wants to delete
      var warning = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?");
      if (warning == true) {
         deleteSelectedRows();
      } 
    }
  });
})

</script>
<a id="delete_link">Supprimer</a>
<br><br>
<div id="divtable"><table class="table">
    <tr id="throws"> 
        <tr><th><input id="ck_All" type="checkbox" onchange="checkUncheckAll()" />Select</th>
        <th>Nom</th>
         <th>Email</th>
         <th>Subject</th>
         <th>Messages</th>
          <th>Date Creation</th></tr>
          <tr id="1">
            <td><input name="ck" onchange="selectUnselect(this.checked)" type = "checkbox" /></td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Email</td>' .  
            <td>Subject</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor</td>
            <td>2017-01-01</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="2">
            <td><input name="ck" onchange="selectUnselect(this.checked)" type = "checkbox" /></td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Email</td>' .  
            <td>Subject</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor</td>
            <td>2017-01-01</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```